# Stanford Core NLP NER Tagging: Difference between DATE and DURATION

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I want to retrieve years information from two sentences.

In one case for "5 years" is being tagged as Date
in another case "2 years" is being tagged as Duration.

What is the difference between these two.

Comment: can you also provide 2 input samples to cross check ? 
generally date is 22/07/2019 and duration is 2 minutes, 2 years etc..

Comment: 1. `I have been working as a senior software engineer for last 5 years at xyz corp `    2. `Before that i have worked at small startups as software engineer for 2 years.`

Comment: since it uses last 5 years, it can be used to find definite date and not exactly on the second scenario. (2 years). i presume this. not sure of it exactly